# My Image is not loading in my Modal box even though they are in the same folder

Tags: javascript, php, html, image, bootstrap-modal

I want an image inside my modal box. I am using CodeIgniter and the image is located in the same folder as my modal box's page.

This is my modal code

```
            <div class="modal fade" id="modalWin" tabindex="-1" data-backdrop="false">
              <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="winnerDraw">Drawing Winner</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                      <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <img src="C:\xampp\htdocs\raffle1\application\views\webRaffle.png" height="200px" width="450px">
                    <p>{winner name}</p>

                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

And I already have the necessary boostrap headers as well as script headers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The img.src is pointing at your C drive.

You can use a relative url, say `src="webRaffle.png"`.

Comment: Do you see any errors from "Network" tab in your [browser devtool](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/)? If there is a request to get webRaffle.png and it fails (say status 404), then your server is not serving the image. If there is no request, check the "Elements" tab and see if the img tag is there. Clear your cache and check "Disable cache" under "Network" tab just to be safe.

Comment: It looks like my server is not serving my image. I already cleared my cache and disabled the cache as well. My img tags are existing as per in the elements tab. Any suggestion how I can fix this, please?

Comment: I would try putting the image in `htdocs/raffle1/public` folder and change the image URL to `src="/public/webRaffle.png"` (and try some other paths see what works). Without your server config it's impossible to figure out. I would also recommend learning from scratch how your server works first.